# How to extract substrings dynamically

Tags: r, regex

From the string

```
s <- "|tree| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |house| consectetur adipiscing elit, 
|street| sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et |car| dolore magna aliqua."
```

I want to extract the text after the letters within the |-symbols.

My approach:

```
words <- list("tree","house","street","car")

for(word in words){
   expression <- paste0("^.*\\|",word,"\\|\\s*(.+?)\\s*\\|.*$")
   print(sub(expression, "\\1", s))
}
```

This works fine for all but the last wortd `car`. It instead returns the entire string s.
How can I modify the regex such that for the last element of words-list in prints out `dolore magna aliqua.`.

\Edit: Previously the list with expressions was a,b,c,d. Solutions to this specific problem cannot be generalized very well.

Comment: For getting the regex right, I'd recommend taking a look at http://regex.inginf.units.it/ if you're not very comfortable with it

Comment: I always find using `sub` in these cases confusing, since you have to specify what you DON'T want to keep instead of (the more natural) what you DO want to keep. I'd advise using `stringi::stri_extract_all`, for example: `stringi::stri_extract_all(regex = "(?<=\\|[abcd]\\| )([^\\|]+)", s)`. This uses a [lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to match the `|a|`, `|b|`, `|c|` and `|d|` without capturing it.

Comment: Thanks, suppose the expressions I am looking for are not `a,b,c,d` but instead `tree,house,street,car`. How would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting all the words with corresponding values using `stringr::str_match_all`:

```
s <- "|tree| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |house| consectetur adipiscing elit, 
|street| sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et |car| dolore magna aliqua."
words1 <- list("tree","house","street","car")
library(stringr)
expression <- paste0("\\|(", paste(words1, collapse="|"),")\\|\\s*([^|]*)")
result <- str_match_all(s, expression)
lapply(result, function(x) x[,-1])
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Vcf3YL)

Output:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]     [,2]                                            
[1,] "tree"   "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "                  
[2,] "house"  "consectetur adipiscing elit, \n"               
[3,] "street" "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et "
[4,] "car"    "dolore magna aliqua."
```

The regex is

```
\|(tree|house|street|car)\|\s*([^|]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/atTmj0/1), details:

- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(tree|house|street|car)` - Group 1: one of the `words`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `([^|]*)` - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than `|`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(stringi)

s <- '|a| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |b| consectetur adipiscing elit, 
|c| sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et |d| dolore magna aliqua.'

stri_split_regex(s, '\\|[:alpha:]\\|')

[[1]]
[1] ""                                                " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "                  
[3] " consectetur adipiscing elit, \n"                " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et "
[5] " dolore magna aliqua."
```

Comment: or `stringr::str_split( s, pattern = "\\|[a-z]\\| ")`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this pattern

```
library(stringr)
s <- "|tree| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |house| consectetur adipiscing elit, 
|street| sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et |car| dolore magna aliqua."

str_extract_all(s, regex("(?<=\\|)\\w+(?=\\|)"))
#[1] "tree"   "house"  "street" "car"
```

- `(?<=\\|)`: Look behind, position following by |; `\\|`: is an escape for |
- `\\w`: word characters
- `(?=\\|)`: Lookahead, position followed by |